# how to create a program to have an output so it repeats each letter once more as it goes down the word?

Tags: python

using python how can i get an out out to look like this dooggg so each letter it repeats once more. i have tried something that looks like this

```
# Program 21
def double(source):
  pile = ""
  for letter in source:
    pile = pile+letter+letter
    print pile
  print pile
```

but it comes out looking like

```
dd
ddoo
ddoogg
```

Comment: pseudo-code-ish: `for ...;  i++; pile .= str_repeat(letter, i)'`

Answer (score 1):

```
 "".join(l*i for i,l in enumerate(my_word,1))
```

I think should do it

Comment: So much faster than me! Genius Joran Beasley!...and of course so much cleaner!

Answer (score 1):

Try...

```
def double(source):
    word = []
    for x in range(len(source)):
        word.append(source[x]*(x+1))
        print ''.join(map(str, word))


double("dog")

input()
```

and if you want it all on one line try this for python 2:

```
def double(source):
    word = []
    for x in range(len(source)):
        word.append(source[x]*(x+1))
    print ''.join(map(str, word)),


double("dog")

input()
```

and this for python 3:

```
def double(source):
    word = []
    for x in range(len(source)):
        word.append(source[x]*(x+1))
    print(''.join(map(str, word)), end="")


double("dog")

input()
```

Comment: this would be perfect but i don't want it going down a line like  it does i just want one line like dooggg

Comment: So you want it all on one line?

Comment: yea that would be great

Comment: I think I have added a version for python 2 as well - could you test it for me?

Comment: Sweet, glad i could help